# Xodus Java: cannot find symbol PersistentEntityStores

Tags: java, xodus

I am trying to use Xodus but when I write this code:

```
PersistentEntityStore store = PersistentEntityStores.newInstance("glosses-test");
final StoreTransaction txn = store.beginTransaction();
```

I get the following error:

```
XodusTest.java:[28,39] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable PersistentEntityStores
  location: class edu.example.XodusTest
1 error
```

The `pom.xml` file includes the following:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.xodus</groupId>
        <artifactId>xodus-openAPI</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.124</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.xodus</groupId>
        <artifactId>xodus-environment</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.124</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.xodus</groupId>
        <artifactId>xodus-entity-store</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.124</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.xodus</groupId>
        <artifactId>xodus-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.124</version>
    </dependency>
```

What could be the reason? I am using Netbeans 11.2.

Comment: How do you import PersistentEntityStores?

Comment: NetBeans doesn't suggest any way to do so, so I try `import jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.PersistentEntityStores;`

Comment: It just magically started working. Probably a Netbeans bug.